# Remote Desktop Connection cannot connect

Tags: windows-server-2016, rdp, remote-desktop-services

I have used remote desktop load balancing for about three years with little issue until yesterday, when my some, but not all, of my users started reporting an error similar to the following.

> The remote computer BETA.domain.com that you are trying to connect to
> is redirecting you to another remote computer named ALPHA.domain.com.
> Remote Desktop Connection cannot verify that the computers belong to
> the same RD Session Host server farm. You must use the farm name, not
> the computer name, when you connect to an RD Session Host server farm.

I was able to reproduce this error once, but have not been able to again. Not all users gets this issue. In fact, I have one user report that he can remote in from one PC, but not another. All four RDSs *are* listed as RD Session Hosts in 2016 Server Manager under the collection I originally named, both on the connection broker server and all other servers, including those not in the collection. I never remember setting-up a 'server farm', only a server collection, nor have I made any DNS entries. And everything worked fine for three years until yesterday. At this point, I am looking for any direction that will allow me to determine what caused this issue.

Comment: I have done some testing on an old PC I have in storage. I believe this is a client issue, specifically related to a recent update to Win10 [KB5018410]. Connection worked until this patch got installed. Got the error mentioned when connecting with the broker. I did not get this but once on my current Win11 PC. I do not understand how a client can foul a server interaction like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have this problem with W10 clients after KB5018410 is applied. I think it's a bug in client. Workaround is to change RDP file on client:

old value: `use redirection server name:i:0`

new value: `use redirection server name:i:1`

or:

check "Always ask for credentials"

It occurs when user use stored credentials only.

Comment: Both solutions work for me. A good alternative to uninstalling the October cumulative for Win10. Thank you.